# How to get the length of this array without strlen(), sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); does not work, C language

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

This program, tokenizes a user input string, removes extra spaces and saves each word into a 2D array and then print the tokens

**EXAMPLE:**

**input:** `"  Hello     world   string house and car"`

**output and EXPECTED output:**

`token[0]: Hello

token[1]: world

token[2]: string

token[3]: house

token[4]: and

token[5]: car`

***THE PROBLEM:***

the problem is that I achieved this by using `strlen()` function when printing the tokens(code located at the very bottom), I am not supposed to use any other library than `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`, since `strlen()` function is defined in string.h i tried to use `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);` but it does not work as I want, the result using sizeof is :

> `token[0]: Hello
>
>   token[1]: world
>
>   token[2]: string
>
>   token[3]: house
>
>   token[4]: and
>
>   token[5]: car
>
>   �oken[6]:  ��
>
>   token[7]: �
>
>   token[8]: ����
>
>   token[9]: �
>
>   token[10]:`

***I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE THE EXPECTED OUTPUT WITHOUT USING STRLEN()***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRUE 1
char tokenize(char *str, char array[10][20])
{
    int n = 0, i, j = 0;

    for(i = 0; TRUE; i++)//infinite loop until is the end of the string '\0'
    {
        if(str[i] != ' '){
        //position 1, char 1
            array[n][j++] = str[i];// if, it is not space, we save the character
        }
        else{
            array[n][j++] = '\0';//end of the first word
            n++;// position for next new word
            j=0;// start writting char at position 0
        }
        if(str[i] == '\0')
            break;
    }
    return 0;

}
//removes extra spaces
char* find_word_start(char* str){
    /*also removes all extra spaces*/
    char *result = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) *1000);

    int c = 0, d = 0;

    // no space at beginning
    while(str[c] ==' ') { 
        c++; 
    }
    while(str[c] != '\0'){  // till end of sentence
        result[d++] = str[c++]; //take non-space characters

        if(str[c]==' ') { // take one space between words
            result[d++] = str[c++]; 
        } 
        while(str[c]==' ') { // 
            c++; 
        } 
    }
    result[d-1] = '\0';

    //print or return char?
    return result;
    free(result);

}
int main()
{
    char str[]="  Hello     world   string dudes and dudas  ";
    //words, and chars in each word
    char arr[10][20];

    //call the method to tokenize the string
    tokenize(find_word_start(str),arr);
    int row = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
for(int i = 0;i <= strlen(arr);i++)
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    printf("token[%d]: %s\n", i, arr[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which output does the code presented produce?  You should probably provide the code for both results.  It is not necessary to post all the code, just the output loop and the declarations of the variables/arrays used.  The code you have shown using `strlen()` is not valid, because `arr` is not a string, it is an array of strings.  It is not at all clear how that code could have produced either  of the results shown.  `row` is unused, I suspect this code relates to neither output.

Comment: strlen and `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` do completely different things. you should read about them. when you understand what strlen does then you can easily implement your own version of strlen and have satisfied the requirement!

Comment: @clifford it's there at the beginning, right after the "EXAMPLE:" that is the output using `strlen()` and thats the expected output as well, but i cant use strlen() i need another option.

Comment: OK - I see what you are trying to do - it is confusing because you are asking about `strlen()`, when in fat you want to know the number of strings copied to  `arr`.  Neither of your implementations actually work - your `strlen()` solution appears to work by shear luck.  Replace "Hello" with "Goodbye" and watch it fail!  You don't in fact want either the length of the array _or_ `strlen()` in this case.  This is an X-Y problem - hence the confusion. You asked about your solution, not your problem.

Comment: @BerndElkemann : Except it turns out that he in fact wants neither - what he really needs is the number of tokens extracted by `tokenize()`.  A simple thing mae complicated by an [X-Y question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem#targetText=XY%20problem&targetText=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20a,them%20to%20resolve%20issue%20X.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code using `strlen()` may appear the work in this instance but it is not correct.

`strlen(arr)` makes no semantic sense because `arr` is not a string.  It happens in this case to return 5 because `arr` has the same address as `arr[0]`, then you kludged it to work for the 6 word output by using the test `i <= strlen(arr)` in the for loop.  The two values `strlen(arr)` and the number of strings stored in `arr` are not related.

The expression `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` determines the run-time constant number arrays within the array of arrays `arr` (i.e. 10), not the number of valid strings assigned.  It is your code's responsibility to keep track of that either with a sentinel value such as an empty string, or by maintaining a count of strings assigned.

I suggest you change `tokenize` to return the number of strings (currently it is inexplicably defined to return a char, but in fact only ever rather uselessly returns zero):

```
int tokenize( char* str, char array[][20] )
{
    ...

    return n ;
}
```

Then:

```
int rows = tokenize( find_word_start(str), arr ) ;

for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
    printf( "token[%d]: %s\n", i, arr[i] ) ;
}
```